# HTML5 canvas fade image in

Tags: html5-canvas

I simply want to fade in an image if a canvas has been untouched for x amount of seconds:

If you see, an image is loaded into the canvas "robot_redux.png" which is erased on swipe, mousemove.

http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/Projects-2014/xmas-game/

After x amount of seconds, I'd like to make that image reappear. Not sure how though.

Comment: could you show your code please ?

Comment: I posted it in the link

Comment: The code you want us to look at is buried in a link to your link and is 300+ lines long.  ....And its someone else's plugin.  ....And you have not attempted to modify the plugin to meet your new  needs.  ....And you have asked and been answered this same question before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534247/html-canvas-freezing-over-animation.  Kindly start with your previously answered question.  If you have coding problems after attempting to change the plugin to meet your needs, then please come back to Stackoverflow with a small focused snippet of code you need help with.